# UILabel text color not changing for iOS 7 from awakeFromNib method

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, nib

I have created a xib file for my custom `UITableViewCell` and there are some labels in the corresponding xib file. I want to set text color of those labels from `awakeFromNib` method of the custom `UITableViewCell` class. The problem is that it's working fine only for iOS 8 and not for iOS 7.

Answer (score 0):

I think there is a difference in accessing the subviews between iOS7 and iOS8, it could be related to the below condition as well

```
NSArray *subviews;

if(system version is >= iOS 7)
    subviews = aCell.contentView.subviews;
else
    subviews = aCell.subviews;
```

Also you can refer the following link -

[TableViewCell subviews can't access in IOS 7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23285306/tableviewcell-subviews-cant-access-in-ios-7)